# Tkinter: Highlight/Colour specific lines of text based on a keyword

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I looking for a simple way to search through a line of text and highlight the line if it contains a specific word. I have a tkinter text box that has lots of lines like:

"blah blah blah Failed blah blah"

"blah blah blah Passed blah blah"

and I would like to set the background colour of the "Failed" line to be red. so far I have:

```
for line in results_text:
   if "Failed" in line:
      txt.tag_config("Failed", bg="red")
      txt.insert(0.0,line)
   else:
      txt.insert(0.0,line)
```

this prints out what everything I want but does nothing to the colours

this clearly is the wrong way to change the text colour. Please help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Text.search](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.search-method).

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
t = Text(root)
t.pack()
t.insert(END, '''\
blah blah blah Failed blah blah
blah blah blah Passed blah blah
blah blah blah Failed blah blah
blah blah blah Failed blah blah
''')
t.tag_config('failed', background='red')
t.tag_config('passed', background='blue')

def search(text_widget, keyword, tag):
    pos = '1.0'
    while True:
        idx = text_widget.search(keyword, pos, END)
        if not idx:
            break
        pos = '{}+{}c'.format(idx, len(keyword))
        text_widget.tag_add(tag, idx, pos)

search(t, 'Failed', 'failed')
search(t, 'Passed', 'passed')

#t.tag_delete('failed')
#t.tag_delete('passed')

root.mainloop()
```