# Tag everything in a row after a certain character [tkinter Text widget]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

As a coding challenge, I've been building a rich-text editor. So far, I've made working save/save as/load systems and working Headers. But, when you save as .txt all the heading data is lost. So I've been thinking about doing a system that relies on '#' to mark headers (basically syntax highlighting)(#-H1,##-H2,###-H3...). I've looked around, and haven't found anything of the sort. So far, I use this as my system of headings:

```
editor.tag_configure('heading7', font=heading7_font)
removeTags()
editor.tag_add('heading7', SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)
```

*heading7_font=("Consolas Bold", 16), removeTags(): lists through tags and removes all.
Basically, you just select on an OptionMenu if you wish to change the fontsize (or use a certain bind). This question is problably too vague, but, I would very much like so direction or an answer.

Here's the code of my entire project (YES, I know I'm not using classes, and it's a jittery mess, but, I'm going to work on that later): https://pastebin.com/wthVT6q4 (Here's the stylesheet variables: https://pastebin.com/WrX4EDKM)

Comment: `#` `##` are used as headers by [Markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to re-create a basic version of Markdown in my program. And the title says it, I'm asking how to tag everything in a row in a Text widget in tkinter after a certain symbol (like * or #).

Comment: you would have to find this positon on your own - it is text so use string functions or regex - and then use this position as `"line.columns"` in `tag_add` - ie. `"1.0"` for first char (column `0`) in first line (`1`) - doc: [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter: Highlight/Colour specific lines of text based on a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829713/tkinter-highlight-colour-specific-lines-of-text-based-on-a-keyword)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the text widget `search` method to search for a string or a pattern. Then it's just a matter of applying the tag to the results.

This is how it is documented in the `Text` class:

```
search(self, pattern, index, stopindex=None, forwards=None, backwards=None, exact=None, regexp=None, nocase=None, count=None, elide=None)
    Search PATTERN beginning from INDEX until STOPINDEX.
    Return the index of the first character of a match or an
    empty string.
```

As you can see, you can use the `search` method to search on a regular expression. Since you won't always know the length of the matched text, you can specify an `IntVar` to be given the count of the matching characters.

For example, to search for a line that begins with `##` you can do something like this:

```
count_var = tk.IntVar()
index = editor.search(r'## .*', "1.0", "end", count=count_var, regexp=True)
```

With that, you can use `index` as the start of the range, and `"{} +{} chars".format(index, count_var.get())` for the end of the range. Or, use `"{} lineend".format(index)"` to add the highlight to the entire line.

If you only want to highlight the characters after `##`, you can adjust `index` in a similar way: `"{}+{}chars".format(index, 3)`

Note: the regular expression syntax must follow the [rules of Tcl regular expressions](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm). Conceptually the same, they differ from python's rules in some of the special character classes.

Comment: Had to do a little more tweaking to get my perfect solution, but you really helped me thanks!